# javascript shorthand if the else callback

Tags: javascript, shorthand, shorthand-if

the long hand if in javascript would look:

```
function somefunction(param){

    if(typeof(param) != 'undefined'){
           var somevar = param;
         } else {

           alert('ERROR: missing parameter in somefunction. Check your form'); 
           return;

         }

}
```

AND MY SHORT HAND VERSION IS:

```
function somefunction(param){

    param = typeof(param) != 'undefined' ? param : function(){alert('ERROR: missing parameter in somefunction. Check your form'); return;}

}
```

BUT it does not work.

How could I?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only declaring the function. you have to execute it. Add () next to the definition ..

```
function somefunction(param){
    param = typeof(param) != 'undefined' ?
                param :
                function() {
                    alert('ERROR: missing parameter in somefunction. Check your form'); 
                    return false;
                }();
}
```

EDIT: The above is not functionally equivalent to the original as the function itself doesn't return anything and doesn't end the function execution.

```
function somefunction(param) {
    if (typeof(param) == 'undefined') {
        alert('ERROR: missing parameter in somefunction. Check your form'); 
        return false;
    }

    // Use param
}
```

Comment: But that's not equivalent to the original function: it sets param to false rather than returning false from somefunction().

Comment: @nx6 Yes, You are right and I am glad you pointed this out. I'm newby and did not account for the "return something" implication. Still, amit_g's solution does what I intended. I am interested in triggering a warning rather than setting the variable, so, I have edited question, to simply return; as in get out of function THANKS you'r comment enlightened me... I feel like a match now